# Uploading Datagridview data to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

i created a simple mass upload of data from CSV to datagridview and save all datagridview rows into my MySQL table, the code works perfectly but when i check my database it insert a null values to my table heres my code.

This is my Button for Adding all values from my Datagridview

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

        connection.Open()
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2

            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(i)

            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_handling(tbl_docnumber,tbl_bpref,tbl_cname) values (@docnumber,@bref,@cname)", connection)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@docnumber", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@bref", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        connection.Close()
        connection.Dispose()
       
        MessageBox.Show("Data All Uploaded")

    End Sub
```

This is my code on inserting CSV file to my Datagrid view

```
Private Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelectData.Click

        Dim fName As String = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\TestFile"
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files(*.csv)|*.csv"
        OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        Dim colespected As Integer = 5

        Dim sline As String = ""



        If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Dim thereader As New StreamReader(fName, Encoding.Default)
            Do
                sline = thereader.ReadLine
                If sline Is Nothing Then Exit Do

                Dim words() As String = sline.Split(",")
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add("")

                For ix As Integer = 0 To 2
                    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(ix).Value = words(ix)
                Next

            Loop
            thereader.Close()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use a `TextFieldParser` to read the data into a `DataTable` and then bind that to the `DataGriidView`. You can then save the data to the database from the `DataTable` with a `MySqlDataAdapter` and a single call to its `Update` method.

Comment: it confuses me, @jmcilhinney. can you set an example for this one? or do you have any reference link that i could read?

Comment: It is not clear from your question… Are all the items from the csv file displayed in the cells in the `DataGridView`? If the grid fills with data  then the DB Table should insert all the data from the grid except for the last row. Point being if the grid shows data, then the DB table should also show the data. Can you clarify if the grid is actually filled with data?

Comment: In my tests, if the grids `AllowUsersToAddRows` is `true` (the default), then the cells will contain `null` values using the code in the `btnUpload_Click` event. The code in the `btnUpload_Click` event will only work if the grids `AllowUsersToAddRows` is `false`.

Comment: @JohnG Sorry, yes currently csv file display data all the data to the datagridview, but when i try to add all the items in the display data in datagridview it results to null value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your data is displaying successfully in the grid. So I am only addressing the Button event.

Both commands and connections need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks do this for you. (BTW `Stream` objects should be in `Using` blocks also.) Database objects should be local to the method where they are used. If you `.Dispose` a connection how do you expect to `.Open` it later? The command and parameters collection are only created once outside the loop. Just the `.Value` changes inside the loop.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_handling(tbl_docnumber,tbl_bpref,tbl_cname) values (@docnumber,@bref,@cname)", connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@docnumber", MySqlDbType.Int64)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bref", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cname", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
        connection.Open()
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
            cmd.Parameters("@docnumber").Value = CLng(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
            cmd.Parameters("@bref").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            cmd.Parameters("@cname").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Data All Uploaded")
End Sub
```

I am a bit worried that `tbl_docnumber` is an auto-number (identity) primary key in the database. If this is so, then this field should be omitted from the `Insert`.

This operation would be easier if you filled a `DataTable` instead of a `DataGridView`. You could then use a `DataAdapter` to update the database.